# mod_rewrite date subfolder not working

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am having a strange issue that I am perplexed on. I will prelude with that regex is not my strong suit. I need feedback from the community to get this going.

> #### If I have the following URL:
>
> ```
>   http://example.com/2015-03-25/
> ```

#### I want to run those through a PHP file. This rule works great with the following mod_rewrite:

```
 RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
```

> #### But I want to move the folder to:
>
> ```
>   http://example.com/my_pages/2015-03-25/
> ```

#### This rule does not work:

> ```
>  RewriteRule ^/my_pages/?([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
> ```

#### This rules does not work either:

> ```
>  RewriteRule ^my_pages/?([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
> ```

What am I missing here? The communities help is greatly appreciated.

## UPDATE!

### This is what I did to fix the issue:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^my_pages\/([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
> ```
>
> vs.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^/my_pages/?([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
> ```

#### Now, oddly enough, on Apache 2.4, the correct syntax was actually.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^my_pages/?([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
> ```

Comment: I figured it out, updated post with what worked finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE!

### This is what I did to fix the issue:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^my_pages\/([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
> ```
>
> vs.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^/my_pages/?([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
> ```

#### Now, oddly enough, on Apache 2.4, the correct syntax was actually.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^my_pages/?([0-9]){4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])/(.*)$ show_page.php?page=$3 [NC,L]
> ```